# Docker using flink socketwordcount example [apache-flink]

Tags: docker, apache-flink, word-count

I want to use Flink with the help of the docker. I want to run the Socketwordcount instance as a startup. But at this stage I encounter an error. I cannot connect with socket. so after 20 ms the flink finishes working.

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:-flink:1.3.2-hadoop24-scala_2.11-alpine}
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:-flink:1.3.2-hadoop24-scala_2.11-alpine}
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
      - "9000"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - "jobmanager:jobmanager"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
```

After I do docker-compose up, I enter into the running jobmanager.

```
nc -l 6123
```

I'm running.Then I enter the jobmanager container with the help of another terminal

```
./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar -port 6123
```

I'm following instructions in the Flink documentation;
What I want to achieve is to count words sent with nc and write results to .out file. But here the flink closes after 20 ms. When I look at the logs with Docker-compose logs, I see that it is closed because there was no connection established. I'm sorry for my bad english. I do not know what is the problem. If you want to know more about the subject, I can publish the order of my work visually.

Comment: I think it would be nice that you provide the log from `docker-compose logs`

Comment: When I look at the log I receive the message "no connection has been completed because it has not occurred".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I got this working:

First I ran

```
nc -l 9999
```

in a terminal on my laptop (not in a container).

And then I ran

```
./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --hostname 192.168.1.109 --port 9999
```

in the jobmanager container, where 192.168.1.109 is my laptop's IP address.

Finally, I used

```
docker logs stuff_taskmanager_1
```

to see the job's output (where `stuff_taskmanager_1` is the name of the container running the taskmanager, determined by using `docker ps`).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the actual work happens on taskmanager. Jobmanager only coordinates the work. That said the connection is tried to be establish on the taskmanager node. You might try to run

```
nc -l 6123
```

on the taskmanager.

As a tip, the example with Socket connection is not the best for distributed setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well I should follow a method on how to make the socketwordcount instance work. – Could you suggest any source

Comment: I've updated the answer. You may try to start nc on taskmanager.

Comment: I've seen your edit. but I tried it before but it didn't work again. I applied a lot of methods but could not run. so I asked for help from this community. thank you for your help. would love to hear if you have another suggestion.

Comment: netcat isn't available in the taskmanager container, and it doesn't make a lot of sense to install it there. Also, 6123 is the jobmanager port, so it's less confusing to use another port. See my answer for one way to get this working.